# pylint python version inline directive

Tags: python, version, pylint

Is there ready way or workaround to allow inline option for choosing version of pylint

```
#pylint: python2
```

or

```
#pylint: python3
```

so you can type
pylint file.py 
and don't care about which version to use

Comment: How would pylint know which Python version to use when, apparently, you have mixed Python 2 and Python 3 code?

Comment: @SimeonVisser I did not know you can use different versions in one file, is it true?

Comment: I mean your codebase apparently has Python 2 files and Python 3 files. How do you expect pylint to know what file is what?

Comment: @SimeonVisser this is what the question is about. You can add comments in files starting with '#pylint: ' which pylint reads and understands so I am asking if there any way to tell pylint what version to use with such a comment line

Comment: how do you specify the Python version now? Does pylint already support Python 3?

Comment: @SimeonVisser well I have pylint-2.7 and pylint-3.2 in my system and also 'pylint' wrapper that chooses version by looking into `eselect python show` (i use gentoo) so I guess I have to enhance this wrapper so it can look into shebang line to choose python version or something like that. I can tell you when I get it done if you want ;)